# Why I can't choose managed instance group I created when setting up http load balancer in gcloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, autoscaling, gce-instance-group

I'm trying to setup http load balancer, with auto-scaling enabled managed instance group for the back-end service.

The problem occurs when I tried to add instance groups while creating backend service, I already made my managed instance group from an instance template, but I can't see it from adding instance group panel. I chose 'select from existing groups'(not sure it's exact phrase for I'm using foreign language) and  I selected asia region, but I couldn't see/select the group i created.

It gives "no instance groups in this region" message when I choose other regions like US/EU, so I guess it recognizes my group but it just doesn't show up.

http load balancer doesn't support asia region or should I have to modify some other settings to see my group?

fyi, I tried all above action on the cloud console (not with command line)

Any helps would really be appreciated!

Best,
JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently a bug preventing existing instance groups from appearing in the drop-down menu. Until it's fixed, you can add them via gcloud using this command: `gcloud compute backend-services add-backend [backend-service-name] --instance-group [instance-group-name]`.

Comment: I try to add my GKE created instance group to the L7 ingress backend service through your command, but it fails miserably: `Validation failed for instance 'projects/muzhack-1288/zones/europe-west1-d/instances/gke-production-default-pool-de24d27b-7ib1': instance may belong to at most one load-balanced instance group`.

Comment: @aknuds1: I ran into this and was able to fix it by visiting https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/loadbalancing/advanced/backendServices/list and deleting a stray dangling backend service.